# Null termination of string not working it seems

Tags: c

In these two versions:

```
//VERSION 1
char *c=malloc(10);
c[0]='h';
c[1]='i';
c[2]='\0';
c[3]='l';

printf("%s\n",c);
```

I am getting the expected result i.e. `hi` is being printed.

Now in this one:

```
//VERSION 2
char *c;
size_t siz=8;

c=malloc(sizeof(char)*(siz+1));  //char size is 1 byte on system

getline(&c,&siz,stdin);
c[siz]='\0';
printf("%s\n",c);
```

On **inputting** the value 'hello world' the **output** is 'hello world' - I was expecting that it won't print anything after reading 9th byte (it is set to `\0`).

Why is there difference in the two?

Is it happening because pointer `c` in version 2 is made to point to `stdin` and `\0' modification doesn't work that way in a stream? If yes then why is compiler now issuing any warning or error?

Comment: What is `siz` after calling `getline()`?

Comment: 1 should work, for 2, see [man getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) "If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` **and** `*n` is set `0` **before the call**, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Got it - it must be the resizing bu then why assignment of `\0` is not generating error/warning message even with `-Wall`?

Comment: Because in C, bounds checking is *the responsibility of the programmer*, there is no requirement in the C-Standard that any diagnostic be issued (though some compilers will flag it now) Additionally `c[siz]` is *within* bounds for an allocation of `siz+1` -- so nothing is wrong with the assignment. (but if you fail to check the return from `getline` all bets are off and *nul-terminating* at the end of the string is meaningless)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My question was since `c` is pointing to `stdin` - shouldn't assigning anything (in this case `\0`) to `stdin` generate an error/warning?

Comment: The key here is `getline(&c,&siz,stdin);` and the call to `c[siz]='\0';` are completely unrelated. Say getline reads and stores `"hi\n\0"`, the string is terminate at the 4th character. If you come back and then terminated at the 9th character, it will make no difference to `printf("%s\n",c);` because it will cease reading a the 4th character. In your case `getline` does not allocate. It considers the allocation size to be `8` what you provided when you pass `&siz` as a parameter. `getline` will read no more than 7 characters and nul-terminate at `8` preventing you reading a char there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `getline` allocates extra space seeing that `hello world` input exceeds the size provided by `siz` - the return value of `getline` is 11 - Manual says `getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.` - hence the null termination assignment should've either worked or generated a message.

Comment: Yes you are correct there, `8` is just the initial allocation size based on `&siz` instead of the normal `120 bytes`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Are you going to turn you helpful comments into an answer? It seems worth it.

Comment: @Yunnosch - why don't you take this one. I'm about 30 comments deep on another Q trying to get a W10 compile issue sorted out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My pleasure, thanks. That is, I will if it is still unanswered in about 10 hours... ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry, I was lurking and the conversation died like 15 minutes ago so I wrote it up

Comment: @Unn Fine with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you yourself noted in the comments, `getline` will check the pointer and size arguments to see if it needs to reallocate (or allocate) the buffer in the event the line from the stream exceeds the given buffer's size (a `NULL` buffer of size 0 being a plain allocation instead of a reallocation). When this happens, both the pointer and the size arguments are changed to match the new buffer (remember, you passed in pointers to the buffer pointer and size arguments, not just the arguments themselves, references not values).

So, in your example, after allocating a buffer of size 9 chars (9 bytes in your case); your `c` pointer is set to some memory with at least 9 bytes available and `siz` is still 8. However, after typing a line longer than 8 characters (including the new line) like `"hello world\n"`, the buffer is reallocated to fit the whole string `"hello world\n\0"`, ie 13 bytes, AND the size arguments is changed to 13. So, when `getline` returns, `c` points to this new buffer and `siz` is 13. You don't need to add a null termination since `getline` does it for you (assuming it succeeds). What you are doing is then setting `c[13]` to `'\0'` which luckily for you didn't trigger any exceptions as you are accessing past the end of the buffer (making the string `"hello world\n\0\0"`).

For the results you're looking for, keep the original size aside, like in a macro:

```
#define SIZE 8
char* c;
size_t siz = SIZE;
c = malloc(sizeof(char) * (siz +1));
getline(&c, &siz, stdin); // if you type something longer than 8 bytes including new line, it will trigger the realloc and siz will be changed
c[SIZE] = '\0'; // prematurely end the string at 8 bytes
printed("%s\n", c); // now you'll get shorter strings, noting siz will still keep the full length for you
```